# PHP inherit the properties of non-class object

Tags: php, object, inheritance

Is it possible to inherit the properties of a non-class object to another variable?

```
<?php
    
  $obj1 = (object)[
      "prop1"  => "String",
      "prop2"  => "INT"
  ];

  $obj2 = new $obj1;  
  var_dump($obj2->prop1);  // output : Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$prop1

?>
```

I can do instead:

```
  $obj2 = $obj1;    // But, I don't want to pass value. I want properties only with no value or null
```

Comment: Not sure if it is really applicable anywhere.

Comment: Agreed with @u_mulder, please share the use case, why you want to do that. We might have another solution like a class with given fields which can be instantiated, but first let us know your scenario..

Comment: Are you looking for [`clone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, he doesn't want values to be copied. So I think that is not the case.

Comment: I see, I missed that part of the comment

Comment: I just want to know if there's any other way around  to do that without making an actual class. That's the only way I can think of and now I know it's not possible. I know how to do it with a class though.
Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I can't imagine situation where you need this, still I think of 2 workarounds **to get the copy of an object with nulled props**:

```
  // First one: clone object and unset properties via `foreach`
  $obj1 = (object)[
      "prop1"  => "String",
      "prop2"  => "INT"
  ];

  $obj2 = clone $obj1;
  foreach ($obj2 as $propName => $propValue) {
      $obj2->$propName = null;
  }
  var_dump($obj2);
  
  // Second: create new array with keys from original array 
  // and null-values and then convert this array to object
  $obj1 = [
      "prop1"  => "String",
      "prop2"  => "INT"
  ];
  $newArray = array_fill_keys(array_keys($obj1), null);
  $obj2 = (object)$newArray;
  var_dump($obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this:

```
$obj1 = new stdClass;
$obj1->prop1 = "string";
$obj1->prop2 = 1;
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
```